# How to identify button without Xpath in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code is below

```
<button type="submit" class="login-button">Login</button>
```

In selenium I tried below code:-

```
driver.findElement(By.classname("Login")).click();
```

please help me in this code without Xpath

Comment: Add the html for the button

Answer (score 0):

Your classname is `login-button` not `Login`

```
driver.findElement(By.classname("login-button")).click();
```

You can use also partialLinkText

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Login")).click();
```

partialLinkText is looking the Sub-String on HTML DOM

You can use also linkText

```
 driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
```

LinkText is looking the same String on HTML DOM

Using CSS-Selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='login-button']")).click();
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: suggest me another methods

Comment: did you try with the classname I have mentioned and with partialLinkText and linkText.. Is non of them is working?

Comment: if non of them is working that means either you page have an iframe or multiple class name as login-button or multiple text as Login is present on DOM

Comment: There is 8 locators to find the element.. you can't use id or name as your HTML is not having same. Xpath you do not want to use . Now the mainly Cssselector is left which I have added in my answer. please try it

Answer (score 0):

I always Prefer Cssselector rather than Xpath, it's up to the user to choose which they want and what they are comfortable with finding element.

The below link will be very useful if you want to know about CSSSELECTOR.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".login-button")).click();

My suggestion would be Please inspect element and open console
$('.login-button')

Try this one until you get the required element you want. In that way you will be more flexible in getting the most required element.